# State of the art methods for combining deep learning with cost/abnormality detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, anomaly-detection

As the top-1 accuracy on the ImageNet classification challenge is still below 90% ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07678.pdf)), I would like to find those that were not correctly classified.
Idea that comes to mind is using a deep learning architecture and add some specific classes cost or abnormality measure (for example [LOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor)) to the net considerations.

I'm looking for state of the art algorithms which do that (combine deep nets with cost/ abnormality detection) and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you Google "anomaly detection deep learning" it reveals multiple results. Notice that the term is *"anomaly detection"*, not "abnormality".

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if you know what are state of the art methods.